# Best practices for monitoring database dependent events

Tags: python, mysql

What would be best method/approach for creating a python script that is dependent on information in database. For example:

Data is constantly being added to the DB. If standard deviation based on some column "A" goes above 1, 1.5 or 2, based on user preferences they get notified. So if user has setting set at 1.5 he will get notified if St.Dev is above 1.5.

Pushing info to user is not in question, how to optimally monitor database for updates is.

So far i thought of 3 ways:

1. Triggers in MySQL, however problem here is that I would not want to
   leave calculations in MySQL. Not the most efficient solution, I
   would imagine
2. Create a script and run it with crontab that queries the data and checks for parameters and against user preferences.
3. Creating artificial crontab with `While True:` and `sleep` combination

Any other more optimal or out of the box solution that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not done this specifically in MySQL, but triggers are actually plenty optimized in Oracle for most things. I expect MySQL is similar. If you require running the calculation every update, a trigger is definitely the fastest method, and the only guaranteed method to be always up to date.

I suppose if you used an external script, you would only run it every few minutes? This is definitely going to be faster than running a trigger on every update by nature, but MySQL also has time based triggers as well http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

With a trigger, the compiled SQL for the trigger will stay in the database instance's memory most likely. Compiled SQL is plenty fast.

I also think it's generally cleaner to have this sort of thing done as triggers, rather than maintaining external scripts. This is just my opinion though.

If your data is very large you could mess around with moving average formulas, and possibly reduce the total number of calculations. Seems like it would be possible, but I don't have math background to help you with that.

In summary, it would be easy to throw together a sample table and test it with a trigger. Give it a try, I think you'll find it suites your performance needs. If it doesn't I'de be interested in seeing the results.